# How can I include the row names of a dataframe instead of only the numbers using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I am working with, and have performed a k-means clustering analysis. I am trying to generate the cluster plot graph, but cannot seem to re-label the graph to include the row names (and not the numbers). How can I do this? I do not want the row numbers in the image.

Here is the data and code (data has already been normalized for ease of analysis):

```
# Open libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)

# Data
data <- data.frame(label = c('K1',
                          'K2',
                          'K3',
                          'K4',
                          'K5',
                          'K6',
                          'K7',
                          'K8',
                          'K9',
                          'K10',
                          'K11',
                          'K12',
                          'K13',
                          'K14',
                          'K15',
                          'K16',
                          'K17',
                          'K18',
                          'K19',
                          'K20'),
                price = c(-0.624434769750764,
                          -0.536599938797358,
                          -0.644183377954367,
                          1.89585408542367,
                          -0.982659691833129,
                          -0.835733232884629,
                          -1.10200036294203,
                          1.0702916454921,
                          -0.845431392672383,
                          -0.60717549444702,
                          -0.772305180090069,
                          0.489522844465606,
                          0.49759411259524,
                          0.567213760967889,
                          0.41156375566992,
                          1.76934999015057,
                          -0.548828699133812,
                          -0.580000479793385,
                          -0.517891659889718,
                          1.89585408542367),
                control = c(0.707555348515056,
                            0.338078487882797,
                            0.0631189636913435,
                            0.939552447051593,
                            -0.8648694304548,
                            -1.09400236728101,
                            -0.478207599560573,
                            -0.452430144167626,
                            0.887997536265696,
                            -3.03017568346247,
                            -0.607094876525316,
                            0.887997536265696,
                            1.25461023518763,
                            0.137587168159862,
                            1.0541189154647,
                            0.456225158433809,
                            -0.0342625344597922,
                            -0.549811642318762,
                            -0.400875233381728,
                            0.784887714693904))

# Assign row names
rownames(data) <- data$label
data <- data[,-1]

# Computing k-means clustering
k3 <- kmeans(data, centers = 3, nstart = 25)

# Produce cluster plot
fviz_cluster(k2, data = soy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to obtain something like this?

[image]

Heres my code:

```
k3 <- kmeans(data, centers = 3, nstart = 25)


fviz_cluster(k3, 
             data = data, 
             geom = "point", 
             ggtheme = theme_minimal()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(data)),
            vjust = 1.5, 
            hjust = 0.5, 
            size = 3) +
  labs(title = "K-Means Clustering")
```